# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ValueError'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

So I was having issues with errors using the tld library where it didn't know how to handle certain proxy request urls.  To fix this a few exceptions were added and it worked for a particular days worth of data.

```
import tld
from tld import get_fld

#Custom try-except function to handle IPs and garbage http requests
def try_get_fld(x):
    try: 
        return get_fld(x)
    except tld.exceptions.TldBadUrl: 
        return np.nan
    except tld.exceptions.TldDomainNotFound:
        return np.nan

#Apply the function above to the request dataframe
request['flds'] = request['request'].apply(try_get_fld)
```

But on a different day I ran into a new error:

```
ValueError: Invalid IPv6 URL
```

So I added to the exceptions:

```
def try_get_fld(x):
    try: 
        return get_fld(x)
    except tld.exceptions.TldBadUrl: 
        return np.nan
    except tld.exceptions.TldDomainNotFound:
        return np.nan
    except tld.exceptions.ValueError:
        return np.nan
```

Then I ran into an Attribute error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ValueError'
```

So I added that to the exceptions:

```
def try_get_fld(x):
    try: 
        return get_fld(x)
    except tld.exceptions.TldBadUrl: 
        return np.nan
    except tld.exceptions.TldDomainNotFound:
        return np.nan
    except tld.exceptions.ValueError:
        return np.nan
    except tld.exceptions.AttributeError:
        return np.nan
```

Then I get the AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ValueError' again.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong or how to fix my issue?  The goal is just to mark the request urls with NaN so that I can apply the method to my dataset.

Comment: Just use `except ValueError`, it's a base Python `Error` class.

Comment: Changed it up.  Thank you @andrew_reece

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `ValueError` is a Python built-in exception, not a member of `tld`. Use `except ValueError` instead of `tld.exceptions.ValueError`.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify a list of exceptions, make your code concise.

```
def try_get_fld(x):
    try: 
        return get_fld(x)
    except (tld.exceptions.TldBadUrl, 
            tld.exceptions.TldDomainNotFound, 
            ValueError): 
        return np.nan
```